# Azure Kudu install python libraries inside D:\home\python364x86\Lib

Tags: python, azure, kudu

From Site extensions tab, I installed python 3.6 in the following path `D:\home\python364x86`

I also set the environment variable through `Configuration` -> `Path mappings`

`Extension`: `fastCgi`

`Script processor`: `D:\home\python364x86\python.exe`

`Arguments`: `D:\home\python364x86\wfastcgi.py`

Saved and restarted the web app.

In the Kudu cmd debug console, at the root `D:\home\python364x86` I installed a library.

`python -m pip install python-telegram-bot --user`

It successfully installs, but why is it installing in a different path? For example, I checked that the library was installed inside `D:\local\AppData\Python\Python36\site-packages`

How can I install libraries inside `D:\home\python364x86\Lib\site-packages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I install libraries inside
>   D:\home\python364x86\Lib\site-packages

Navigate to path **D:\home\python364x86\Lib\site-packages** in the site extension and install your libraries as below:

```
D:\home\python364x86\Lib\site-packages\python.exe -m pip install python-telegram-bot
```

In order to navigate to the path, you can click on the folders in the site extension and you can observe that paths are changing in the powershell/cmd console.

Comment: Did you mean by `Debug console`? site extension is the tab where you can download modules

Comment: Nope it still installs in `D:\local\AppData\Python\Python36\site-packages`. Have you tried?

Comment: yeah I was in the right path. Soo weird it installs in a different directory. is there a way to set a default path to `D:\home\python364x86`?

Comment: i wonder if you have also tried installing `talib` library. My next step is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885946/install-python-talib-library-in-azure-kudu)