# install python talib library in azure kudu

Tags: azure, kudu, ta-lib

I keep failing to install `talib` library in Azure's Kudu Debug console.

From `D:\home\python364x86` I ran `python -m pip install Ta-Lib` but got this error

> Command "D:\home\python364x86\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='D:\local\Temp\pip-build-az9dvnof\talib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record D:\local\Temp\pip-1737i4ol-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in D:\local\Temp\pip-build-az9dvnof\talib\

Anyone successfully installed `talib` in Kudu debug console?

Comment: Are you able to install it locally on your dev machine?

Comment: Yes. Doing it locally, I followed from this [link](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html). I had to download Dependencies first. `Download ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip and unzip to C:\ta-lib`

Comment: Try doing the same on Kudu. Make sure your are using correct path and not to use **--user** flag as user flag will install it in **D:\local\**\**

Comment: ok so i would create a folder `ta-lib` in `D:`?

Comment: damn actually I can't in `D:` I will try with `D:\home`

Comment: Check in local and check where your main module got installed. It will give you hint t make use of right path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199293/discussion-between-anish-k-and-bbusdriver).